# C# Cross-Account Kinesis using amazon-kinesis-client-net

Tags: c#, amazon-kinesis

I am looking for a KCL in C# for an enhanced fanout for a kinesis. I saw this lib in .net for KCL which basically downloads and calls jar files. However, I dont see a way to use this KCL for a kinesis which is to be accessed cross account using a sts assume role.

Source - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net

Is there a way to use this kcl in .net for cross-accounts as well?